# Liferay 7.0 Search Hook

Tags: liferay, liferay-7

I'm working with `Liferay 7.0 GA3` and I want to customize the Search Portlet.

1. With the default portlet I can select between sites, asset entries,
   folders, users and time when I'm looking at the page as `Guest`, but
   when I'm logged I can see sites, asset entries, tags, categories,
   folders, users and time. I would need to **show only** asset entries
   (documents and web content articles, but no documents folder and web
   content folders), categories and time.
2. Another problem is that I imported the data from another server and
   now when I search something being a `Guest`, the porlet only shows me
   documents but no web content. However, if I'm logged the porlet
   works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know what is the problem with the point 2 yet, but a provisional solution is to go to:

1. **Users** -> **Roles** and select **Define Permissions to Guest**.
2. Navigate to **Site Administration** -> **Content** -> **Web Content**
3. Check the box **View** associated with **Web Content Article**.